# Proof of Tychonoff's Theorem using subbasic open subsets

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness, product-space

I am reading a textbook proving the Tychnoff's theorem, which states that any product of compact spaces is compact.

The proof goes like this:

> Let $X=\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$, where each $X_\alpha$ is
>   compact. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a family of subbasic sets of the form
>   $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in A$ and $U_\alpha$ is an
>   open subset of $X_\alpha$. **Suppose that no finite subfamily of
>   $\mathcal{D}$ covers $X$. In view of the Alexander Subbase Theorem, it
>   suffices to show that $\mathcal{D}$ does not cover $X$.**

I wonder why it suffices to show that $\mathcal{D}$ does not cover $X$. The Alexander Subbase Theorem says that if every open cover of $X$ by sets in subbase has a finite subcover, then $X$ is compact. By the above proof, we can show that if $\mathcal{D}$ covers $X$, then there is a finite subcover. How can we show that for every open cover (not just $\mathcal{D}$ itself), there is a finite subcover?

Comment: You are just, in a sense, "rephrasing" Alexander Subbase Theorem's statement.

Answer (score 0):

If the space $X$ is not compact, there *is* an open cover, consisting of sets in a subbase, such that no finite subfamily covers $X$.

If you show that any family, with the property that no finite subfamily covers $X$, is not a cover, you have shown it is false that $X$ is not compact.

Comment: Yes. But we have to show that ANY family, with the property that no finite subfamily covers $X$, is not a cover. However, the proof says that we only need to show that $\mathcal{D}$, with such property, is not a cover.

Comment: @SHBaoS I don't understand: $\mathcal{D}$ is an arbitrary family with the property.

Comment: Oh I see why the statement makes sense. Thank you. Yes, $\mathcal{D}$ is arbitrary.